# Fixed effect model with only dummy variable in R

Tags: r

I am new to both R and stats and doing a model replication exercise on R. 
The model test how trade liberalization of 50 countries affects energy consumption. 
E = a0 + a1i + a2t + a3*LIBit + nit, where E indicated energy consumption, a0 is the constant, a1i is the country fixed effect, a2t is the time fixed effect, LIBit is the dummy variable for trade liberalization.
There are three levels of trade liberalization and dummy 0 is used for "before lib" and dummy 1 is used for "during lib" and "after lib" in the orignial model.

When I use lm() to test the model with only country fixed effect, it seems to work fine. But the warning "coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)" pops up when i use it for country and time fixed effect.
I tried plm() too but it significantly deviates from the real results. 
And when I use plm(), I don't seem to get the result for Constant a0 like the original model does. 
Please help!

Comment: The problem with using `lm` in that manner is that it fails to properly account for the repeated measures. You need statistical advice. Or if you want to do some reading on your own search on "panel regression"

Comment: I have been research for a day now and can't find the answer. I don't understand how a single dummy variable with one coefficient can be used for two levels.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, you need statistical education. The comment indicates that you don't understand how treatment contrasts are used to express regression results.